# javascript for loop how to count every four items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering how to count items in for loop in javascript,

For example I have array with 12 values/objects and I wanna append them to list in html but I wanna put befeore every first an `<hr>` tag and before every fourth `<br>`.

now I'm using:

```
var buttons = [ {"tag":"adr","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"ag","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"fax","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"ind","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"sname","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"per","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"tel","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"url","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"url","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"weblink","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"weblink","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"close","color":"#123456"} ];

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    var tag = buttons[i].tag;
    var color = buttons[i].color;

    $(".list").append("<li>"+ tag + ", " + color +"</li>");
}
```

and it just appends items from object to list.

It's maybe hard to describe what is my intention so maybe the best way is to put jsfiddle link where the left list is my current situation and the right on is what I wanna to look it like: 
http://jsfiddle.net/E6qR7/

I have not found any similar specific example so far, what is the best way to do that? I need somehow use iterator, check him in loop or something

Comment: Couple of things; what do you mean by `before every first`? Secondly, you can't have `hr` or `br` tags as a direct child of a `ul`, so they would need to be placed within their own `li`.

Comment: I have updated my answer to use styling instead, which I think is more appropriate as the alternatives all generate invalid HTML (which only works because of browsers being very fault tolerant). It also gives you much finer control of the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this

```
if (i && (i % 4 === 0)) {
    $('.list').append('<hr>');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/E6qR7/1/)

Comment: @dzordz Just a note, not that it necissarily applies to this case.. But in general you shouldnt pick an answer just because it was first, read up on the issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Answer (score 3):

Lots of the other answers are correct, but the minimum expression needed is:

```
    if (i && !(i % 4))
    {
        $('.list').append('<hr>');
    }
```

**I noticed all the other answers (including mine above) do not generate valid HTML, so I would suggest using styling instead and annotate classes onto the LIs**:

### JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/E6qR7/5/

```
var buttons = [ {"tag":"adr","color":"#123456"},
               {"tag":"ag","color":"#123456"},
               {"tag":"fax","color":"#123456"},
               {"tag":"ind","color":"#123456"},
               {"tag":"sname","color":"#123456"},
               {"tag":"per","color":"#123456"},
               {"tag":"tel","color":"#123456"},
               {"tag":"url","color":"#123456"},
               {"tag":"url","color":"#123456"},
               {"tag":"weblink","color":"#123456"},
               {"tag":"weblink","color":"#123456"},
               {"tag":"close","color":"#123456"} ];

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        var tag = buttons[i].tag;
        var color = buttons[i].color;
        var $li = $("<li></li>");
        if (!(i % 4)) {
            $li.addClass('line');
            if (i){
                $li.addClass('break');
            }
        }
        $li.append(tag + ", " + color);
        $(".list").append($li);
    }
```

This also shows a different way of creating elements and filling them (just for clarity)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/E6qR7/3/

```
    if(i % 4 == 0) {
        $(".list").append("<hr />");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using javascript modulus:

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    var tag = buttons[i].tag;
    var color = buttons[i].color;

    if (i % 4 == 0)
        $(".list").append("<hr>");
    $(".list").append("<li>"+ tag + ", " + color +"</li>");
}
```

I figured you could modify it yourself to include the <br> tag ;)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        var tag = buttons[i].tag;
        var color = buttons[i].color;
        if ( i == 0 ) {
            $(".list").append("<hr />");                    
        }
        else if ( i % 4 == 0 ) {
            $(".list").append("<br /><hr />");        
        }
        $(".list").append("<li>"+ tag + ", " + color +"</li>");
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E6qR7/4/

Comment: `if (i==0)`... surely that first `append` just belongs before the for loop :)

Comment: Saw your comment to the SO and would like to also point out that not a single answer results in both what the SO wanted *and* valid HTML. They are all just hints in the right direction :)

Comment: I have updated my answer to suit both the requirements *and* generating valid HTML. See what you think.

Comment: Yes that would make sense, I just left it in the loop to make use of the if else to avoid extra condiditon to stop the br+hr from being appended on the first iteration. +1 to your answer

Answer (score 2):

you should use modulo (%).

```
if (i%4==0) $(".list").append("<hr>");
if (i%4==3) $(".list").append("<br>");
```